# How to compute $\lim_{x\to \infty} x(a^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm supposed to compute it by using some of the following limits somehow:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$$

But I can't find how to make this limit appear in the calculation. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: may be this: $a=\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{\ln a}x)^x$ so $\lim x(a^{1/x}-1)=\ln a.$

Comment: @PNDas I was ALMOST guessing that I had to write $a$ in some funny way!

Comment: May I know  why you need to use those limits only? If you had been allowed to use derivatives, I guess you would have already thought that the limit is the derivative of $a^y$ at $y=0$.

Comment: @Yathi It's the book's idiosyncrasy, something akin to not answering limits with L'hospital, I guess. I'm trying to follow it.

Comment: L'Hospital is not required at all. Simply the definition of derivatives. Aren't you supposed to use the definition of derivatives too?

Comment: @Yathi Yep. I was just making an example of such idiosyncrasies. In the book I'm reading, derivatives comes much later.

Comment: Okay! That's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of writing an answer which would use only the limits you had mentioned:

The given limit, as has been mentioned in my comment and also later in the answer posted above, is equivalent to
$$\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+} \frac{a^y-1}{y}.$$

I am just reiterating how this can be evaluated from first principles.

Now, $a^y = e^{y\ln (a)}$. Thus the limit turns out to be
$$ \ln(a)\lim\limits_{y\to 0^+} \frac{e^{y\ln(a)} - 1}{y\ln(a)}.$$
Putting $h= y\ln(a)$, the above limit is simply,

$$\ln(a) \lim\limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{e^h-1}{h}.$$

The limit above, is easily found out from first principles, which you might be knowing. Yet for the sake of completion, I will rewrite it below:

$\textbf{To find $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^+}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$}$.

Put $e^h -1 = t$. Then, $e^h = 1+t$ and $h = \ln (1+t)$. Thus, the limit turn out to be

$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\ln(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}} = \frac{1}{\ln(e)},$$ where it is required to assume that limit can be taken inside a continuous function.

Well, this does use one of the limits you had mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

The limit you are trying to compute is equivalent to

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^t - 1}{t}$$

because as $x \rightarrow \infty$, we have $t \rightarrow 0$, and this is a basic technique of substitution, and you can find this in every 1st year Calculus book.

Then by $\textbf{L'Hôpital's rule}$, which again you can find in every 1st year Calculus book, we have

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^t - 1}{t} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(a^t - 1)'}{t'} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^t \ln a}{1} = \ln a$$

Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x(a^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^t - 1}{t} = \ln a$$

Comment: Is L'Hosipital required? The limit is simply the definition of the derivative of $a^t$ at $t=0$.

Comment: @Yathi Well I think there isn't huge difference here between using definition of derivative and using L'hopital's rule, and for both methods, we can directly see the answer at first sight. So personally I think it doesn't matter which way we choose.

Comment: @Yathi This is something of a minor pet peeve of mine: using L'Hopital's rule to evaluate a derivative in flagrant disregard for how inefficient it is. Of course ZYX is correct as well: the proof is valid.

Comment: The use of L'Hopital doesn't make much sense here. For that you need to know the derivative of $a^t$ at least in a neighborhood of the origin. The limit itself is just the derivative of $a^t$ at a single point, the origin.

Comment: @Gary Well, I think it makes sense to use LH here, because, the guy who posted the question here only asked how to compute that limit, but didn't say which way we should use. Also, LH can solve this limit at first sight, and this means it is at least as efficient as using other ways here.

Comment: Generally, the derivative of $t\mapsto a^t$ (which is needed for L'Hopital) is determined by first computing this particular limit.