# How to compute $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to compute the following limit:

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x} \tag{1}$$

And I have to use some of the following limits for it:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$$

I tried some substitutions, specially the first limit but I got only to:

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x+1)^a-(x+1)^b}{x} \tag{2}$$

Which I tried to substitute $x$ for $x-1$ but this yielded nothing useful.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: $\frac{{{\rm e}^{ax}  - {\rm e}^{bx} }}{x} = a\frac{{{\rm e}^{ax}  - 1}}{{ax}} - b\frac{{{\rm e}^{bx}  - 1}}{{bx}}$, so the problem reduces to $\lim _{h \to 0} \frac{{{\rm e}^h  - 1}}{h}$. For that, look at the last part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4882387) recent answer.

Comment: When we know that LH rule will give $a-b$ , we know that your reduced limit must be $1$ , @Gary , thus this is a nice method which should be the answer here !

Comment: Alternate hint : We got (2) , where we can expand the Powers with Binomial theorem Extensions. then the $1$ terms will cancel , while the linear terms will give $(a-b)x$ where we can cancel the $x$ with the Denominator. All higher terms will still have $x$. We then get $L=(a-b)$

Comment: The step leading to $(2)$ is not rigorous since $\mathrm{e} \ne (1+x)^{1/x}$. You would need to write it as a double limit involving $\mathrm{e} =\lim_{t\to 0} (1+t)^{1/t}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ L = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{ax}-e^{bx}}{x}\right) $$
$$ L = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{ax}\left(1 - e^{(b-a)x}\right)}{x}\right) $$
$$ L = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(e^{ax} \cdot \frac{1 - e^{(b-a)x}}{x}\right) $$

Notice that as $x \to 0, e^{ax}\to 1$, so we can focus on the second part of the product:

$$ L = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1 - e^{(b-a)x}}{x}\right) $$

Now, let's rewrite $1 - e^{(b-a)x}$ to look more like the provided limits. Use the substitution $$h = (b-a)x$$ As $x \to 0, h \to 0$

$$ L = \lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{1 - e^h}{\frac{h}{b-a}}\right)$$
$$ L = (b-a)\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{1 - e^h}{h}\right) $$
$$ L = -(b-a)\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{ e^h - 1}{h}\right) $$

Let $u=e^h - 1$. Then $e^h = 1+u$ implying $h=\ln(1+u)$. As $h \to 0, u \to 0$ since $1+u \to 1$

$$ \lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{ e^h - 1}{h}\right) = \lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1+u- 1}{\ln(1+u)}\right)$$
$$ = \lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{u}{\ln(1+u)}\right)$$
$$ = \lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{u})\ln(1+u)}\right)$$
$$ = \lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\ln((1+u)^\frac{1}{u})}\right)$$

Let $u=\frac{1}{n}$, so
$$ \lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{ e^h - 1}{h}\right) = \lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\ln((1+u)^\frac{1}{u})}\right) $$
$$ = \lim _{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\ln((1 + \frac{1}{n})^n)}\right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{\ln(e)} $$
$$ = 1 $$

So $$ L = -(b-a)\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{ e^h - 1}{h}\right) $$
$$  = -(b-a) $$
$$  = a-b $$